# I cannot activate NVIM's built-in LSPs for javascript and html

Tags: language-server-protocol, neovim

I am trying to utilize NVIM's built-in LSPs.  While I've been able to implement the LSP for css and python, I haven't been successful with javascript and html.

I installed the LSPs with

```
:LspInstall <LSP>
```

Here's how I'm loading the LSPs:

```
packadd nvim-lspconfig
packadd completion-nvim

:lua << EOF
  local nvim_lsp = require('nvim_lsp')
  local on_attach = function(_, bufnr)
    require('completion').on_attach()
    local opts = { noremap=true, silent=true }
  end
  local servers = {'tsserver', 'cssls', 'html', 'pyls'}
  for _, lsp in ipairs(servers) do
    nvim_lsp[lsp].setup {
      on_attach = on_attach
    }
    print("lsp istalled -", lsp)
  end
EOF
```

:LspInstallInfo shows:

```
{                                                                                                          
  cssls = {
    bin_dir = "~/.cache/nvim/nvim_lsp/cssls/node_modules/.bin",
    binaries = {
      ["css-languageserver"] = "~/.cache/nvim/nvim_lsp/cssls/node_modules/.bin/css-languageserver"
    },
    install_dir = "~/.cache/nvim/nvim_lsp/cssls",
    is_installed = true
  },
  html = {
    bin_dir = "~/.cache/nvim/nvim_lsp/html/node_modules/.bin",
    binaries = {
      ["html-languageserver"] = "~/.cache/nvim/nvim_lsp/html/node_modules/.bin/html-languageserver"
    },
    install_dir = "~/.cache/nvim/nvim_lsp/html",
    is_installed = true
  },      
  tsserver = {
    bin_dir = "~/.cache/nvim/nvim_lsp/tsserver/node_modules/.bin",
    binaries = {
      ["typescript-language-server"] = "~/.cache/nvim/nvim_lsp/tsserver/node_modules/.bin/typescript
-language-server"
    },    
    install_dir = "~/.cache/nvim/nvim_lsp/tsserver",
    is_installed = true
  }       
}
```

They seem to be installed and the LSPs for *.css and *.py work fine.

When I open a *.js, *.ts, or *.html file I get the same response with the :LspInstallInfo command.  However, I don't think the LSP is active because I do not receive any warning or error messages regarless of what I type.

I've tried loading the LSP different ways, including:

```
require'nvim_lsp'.tsserver.setup{}
require'nvim_lsp'.html.setup{}
```

I came across a post about installing typescript and I did, but it didn't seem to have any effect.

I've deactivated all of the other plugins and had the same results.

Answer (score 4):

After installation, you should take consider **root_dir**. So if you don't have a matching root directory LSP doesn't launch.

> In order to automatically launch a language server, lspconfig
> searches up the directory tree from your current buffer to find a file
> matching the root_dir pattern defined in each server's configuration.
> For pyright, this is any directory containing ".git", "setup.py",
> "setup.cfg", "pyproject.toml", or "requirements.txt").
>
> Language servers require each project to have a root in order to
> provide completion and search across symbols that may not be defined
> in your current file, and to avoid having to index your entire
> filesystem on each startup.

**But if you want to launch LSP in any directory, you can use something like this for Javscript:**

```lua
require'lspconfig'.tsserver.setup{
  filetypes = { "typescript", "typescriptreact", "typescript.tsx" },
  root_dir = function() return vim.loop.cwd() end      -- run lsp for javascript in any directory

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was working on setting up neovim 0.5 today and landed up here looking for something else related to LSP. Anyho, I do have a working setup; here's a brief:

1. Install neovim nightly (>= 0.5 version)
2. Install [`nvim-lspconfig`](https://github.com/neovim/nvim-lspconfig) package (I used vim-plug)
3. Install [tsserver](https://github.com/theia-ide/typescript-language-server): `npm i -g typescript-language-server`
4. Add setup in init.vim (remove EOF lines if init.lua):

```
lua << EOF 
require'lspconfig'.tsserver.setup{}
EOF
```

5. Restart neovim

---

I noticed you're using commands like `LspInstall` & `LspInstallInfo`, but they are not present in my setup. I'm afraid I cannot comment of why they it work as expected.

LSP by itself doesn't show autocompletion. Have to use another plugin. I am getting good results with [`completion-nvim`](https://github.com/nvim-lua/completion-nvim)

---

This is a good reference : [neovim-and-its-built-in-language-server-protocol](https://dev.to/casonadams/neovim-and-its-built-in-language-server-protocol-3j8g)

Oh, do give `:help lsp` a read if you haven't already. Cheers!